# XML without root in Linq Select

Tags: c#, html, xml, linq

I have an Index view where I would like show a list of news article, the *Text* property is a string which contains a `html` string coming from a `html` editor; now the `html` content could be really long, so I would like show only the first `<p>` element.
I am doing that:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
      var articles = db.Articles.ToList().Select(a => new{Title = a.Title, 
                                                          Tags = a.Tags, 
                                                          Id = a.Id,
                                                          Text = (System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(a.Text).Descendants("p").FirstOrDefault())
                                                          }).ToList();

      return View(articles);
    }
```

But in the `html` string there is not a **root node**, so the `Linq` query fall in exception, How I can manage this case?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a shorthand solution, but should wrapping your xml in a root node not fix the problem?

```
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(
     String.Format("<myRootNode>{0}</myRootNode>" , a.Text)
    )
```

Comment: damn sometime the simplest solution is the last place where I am search :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using regex

```
static String GetTheFirstPElement(String rawHtml) 
{
    Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"(<p[^>]*>.*?</p>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    MatchCollection matches = myRegex.Matches(rawHtml);

    var firstMatch =  matches.FirstOrDefault() ; 

    return firstMatch != null ? firstMatch.Value : null ; 
}
```